# React js et Redux display data Error: Invalid value of type object for mergeProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

The error I get is the following:

```
Error: Invalid value of type object for mergeProps argument when connecting component Majregion.
```

I am new to redux and have tried various different approaches.

```
Majregion.propTypes   = {
  addRegionMaj : PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  errors : PropTypes.object.isRequired


}

const mapStateToProps = state =>({
  errors : state.errors,
  Region : state.Region,

})



export default connect (mapStateToProps,{getBackLog} ,{addRegionMaj}) (Majregion);


export const getBackLog = () => async dispatch => {

    const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/regions/all")

    dispatch ({
        type : GET_MODELS_REGION,
        payload : res.data
    });


};
```

Note: Everything is working fine, just when i add the methode {getBackLog} in export default connect
please what  i should to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do this:

```
export default connect (mapStateToProps,{ getBackLog ,addRegionMaj }) (Majregion);
```